# FastCGI allowed memory exhausted in Wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress, fastcgi, php7

I have Wordpress running on a Ubuntu 20.04 server with Nginx and PHP 7.4. When trying to generate a feed (by going to a feed URL such as /category/feed) , I receive the following error:

```
2020/09/11 18:51:26 [error] 4446#4446: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal.    error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1251PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.xx, server: www...., request: "GET /category/feed HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "www...."
```

I have tried to increase the memory limit on PHP to higher than 256M but this does not resolve the issue.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What exactly did you do to increase PHP memory limit?

Comment: I set memory_limit = 256M  in php.ini (and tried higher amounts too), restarted php, etc.

Comment: What `php.ini` did you change?

Comment: /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini